# How to use setState in an asynchronous function

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-native, redux-thunk, setstate

I am running this code:

```
.then((url) => {
      if (url == null || undefined) {
          return this.props.image;
      } else {

          const { image } = this.props;

          //entryUpdate is an action creator in redux.
          this.props.entryUpdate({ prop: 'image', value: url })
               .then(() => {
                   this.setState({ loading: false });
               });
```

but I get the following error:

[image]

How do I format setState() inside an asynchronous function that's called after an action creator?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like `this.props.entryUpdate` function is not returning `promise`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out.  I put the .then() function too early.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work, your action creator `this.props.entryUpdate` would need to return a promise for the async work it's doing. Looking at the error message, that does currently not appear to be the case.

You also need to be aware that calling `setState()` in the asynchronous callback can lead to errors when the component has already unmounted when the promise resolves.

Generally a better way is probably to use `componentWillReceiveProps` to wait for the new value to flow into the component and trigger `setState` then.

Answer (score 0):

I placed the .then() function inside of the the if statement.  But it should be like this:

```
.then((url) => {
    if (url == null || undefined) {
      return this.props.image;
    } else {
      const { image } = this.props;
      this.props.entryUpdate({ prop: 'image', value: url })
    }
 })
        .then(() => {
            this.setState({ loading: false });
        });
```